# Split String with special characters to array

Tags: javascript

My Ajax returns a large string of department names like below..

```
var dept='<list>"32001 Dept of (THE) DOE","32010 Dept of "Health"HHS","32021 Dept of DHS,(12/30/2010)","32024 Dept of H&D","32014 Dept of DOJ","32031 Dept of "DOT", Transport"</list>';
```

I want to break apart the 6 departments by the dept number and put it in an array but the description itself have quotes, coma and all special characters.
The only consistent part is the 5digit  dept number in the begning.
how can i resolve this issue..

```
i tried to do..
var start = dept.indexOf("<list>");
var stop = dept.indexOf("</list>");
var deptList = dept.substring(start+7,stop);
var deptlist2 = deptList.split('"');
var deptArr=[];

for(x=0; x<deptlist2.length;x++){
if(deptlist2[x].length>1){
 deptArr.push(deptlist2[x]);
  }
}
```

desired output should be

32001 Dept of (THE) DOE 
32010 Dept of "Health"HHS
32021 Dept of DHS,(12/30/2010)
32024 Dept of H&D
32014 Dept of DOJ
32031 Dept of "DOT", Transport

Thanx for your the help..

Comment: Use a regular expression to search for `\d{5}` to find the department number.

Comment: Why are you mixing XML with CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string on multiple character, i.e. `","`, and the push them into an array.

```
var array = deptList.split('","');
```

I've output them to a `div` in the sample, using a `for` loop.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="output-panel"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var dept = '<list>"32001 Dept of (THE) DOE","32010 Dept of "Health"HHS","32021 Dept of DHS,(12/30/2010)","32024 Dept of H&D","32014 Dept of DOJ","32031 Dept of "DOT", Transport"</list>';

var start = dept.indexOf("<list>");
var stop = dept.indexOf("</list>");
var deptList = dept.substring(start + 7, stop);

var array = deptList.split('","');

var newHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newHTML = newHTML + '<span>' + array[i] + '</span><br/>';
}
$("#output-panel").html(newHTML);
```

### [Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FSyd/1/)

Comment: Thank you.. this works for me.. but curious if can i split the string by searching 5 digit using regex as @barmar mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the sequence `","` can't be found in a department name you can do this:

```
var dept='<list>"32001 Dept of (THE) DOE","32010 Dept of "Health"HHS","32021 Dept of DHS,(12/30/2010)","32024 Dept of H&D","32014 Dept of DOJ","32031 Dept of "DOT", Transport"</list>';

dept = dept.replace(/<\/?list>/g, '');

result = dept.split('","')

console.log(result);
```

http://jsbin.com/boqaw/1

However this is a very bad API you should use JSON or at least XML.